# How to setup GraphDB 10.x.x with JMX?

Tags: graphdb

Prior to GraphDB 10.x, the documentation [had references to setting up JMX](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.8/enterprise/administration-tools.html#configuring-the-jmx-endpoint). These docs have been removed from 10.x, leaving me wondering how to use JMX with this version.

**Question**: How can JMX be run with GraphDB 10.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMX was used historically mostly to provide an easier way to setup a cluster and to connect to query monitoring/system resource monitoring on remote GraphDBs. This evolved into creating REST APIs and it was deprecated in GraphDB 10.X.

All the operations are available in the Cluster and Monitoring REST APIs.

Comment: I'll note that new JMX documentation was added in the 10.3 documentation.
https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/system-monitoring.html#jmx-console-monitoring